# Google Analytics event tracking with PHP in html_output

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm getting category from my database using PHP and I want to use it inside Google Analytics event tracking code. The problem is that events are not being recorded in Google Analytics.

Here are some code snippets from my project:

1)

```
$docs = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$doc = array();
    $doc['my_tel'] = $row['my_tel'];
    $doc['my_category'] = $row['my_category'];

$docs[] = $doc;

}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

2)

```
    <?php
$html_output = '';
foreach ($docs as &$d) {
    $html_output .= '<div>' . 
    '<a href="tel:' . $d['my_tel'] . '" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', ' . $d['my_category'] . ', \'Event Action\', \'Event Label\']);"><img src="call.png" width="65px" height="35px" border="0"></a>' .             
    '</div>';
}
echo $html_output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the console of your browser there might be a JavaScript error, because the second parameter of `_gaq.push` is not wrapped with quotes.

Try this:

```
<?php
$html_output = '';
foreach ($docs as &$d) {
    $html_output .= '<div>' . 
    '<a href="tel:' . $d['my_tel'] . '" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'' . $d['my_category'] . '\', \'Event Action\', \'Event Label\']);"><img src="call.png" width="65px" height="35px" border="0"></a>' .             
    '</div>';
}
echo $html_output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your append to $html_output, it appears you're not enclosing the category within single quotes in the resultant javascript output.

Assuming for example my_tel was 01234567890 and category was 'Category 1' the output from the code above would be:

```
<div><a href="tel:01234567890" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', Category 1, 'Event Action', 'Event Label']);"><img src="call.png" width="65px" height="35px" border="0"></a></div>
```

Perhaps try (note additional escaped quotes around category:

```
'<a href="tel:' . $d['my_tel'] . '" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'' . $d['my_category'] . '\', \'Event Action\',...
```

--dan